# is Program compiled by amd64 compiler executable and possible to run,work properly in x86 cpu?

Tags: c, qt, compatibility

is Program compiled by amd64 compiler executable and possible to run,work properly in x86 cpu??

I wanna know whether it's possible

and also im trying to develop some program in Qt

but I'm wondering at that why there is no qmake.exe that supports MSVC2017 32bit compiler

Comment: It is called "cross compiling" in which in one platform you develop a program and compile it for another platform. But I doubt that is what you mean. If AMD64 and X86-64 have different machine code instructions, then no, it won't run.

Comment: AMD64 on X86 is a total no no. AMD64 on X86-64 however should work for most of the opcodes, unless your binary is using some AMD specific extension. Also there is a *small* set of opcodes that are not common to AMD64 and X86-64.

Answer (score 0):

No. But a program written without reference to specific architecture dependent features (i.e anything written using standard c, c++, etc) can be compiled using different flags for different target architectures.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.3/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html

If you are interested in why, looking at the spec for x86 or x86-64 will give you a sense of the answer.  An architecture specification is alot more than a list of supported machine instruction.  They have different memory architecure, different flags, different cpu modes, etc. And in addition to all this, specifications have hardware specific implementations (chips support different features).  When you compile a executable binary, all of these differences must be taken into account.